# Full height on pseudo element and vertically centering its content

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is it possible to have full height on a pseudo element without `position: absolute`?

If not, how can I center content on pseudo element with `position: absolute`?

**First Codepen without `position: absolute`**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWPoVx

**Second attempt using `position: absolute`** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWELGv

HTML

```
  <div class="fusion-layout-column">
    <div class="fusion-column-wrapper">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS

```
.fusion-layout-column {

  .fusion-column-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 1em;

    &:before {
      content: 'G';
      background: #ddd;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 2em 1em;
      margin-right: 1em;
      height: 100%;
    }

  }
}
```

I am good with using any hack just to make this work in modern browsers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want both full height for the background and full centering for the content, I would split each task among two pseudo-elements.

Below is a simplified version of your code. I'm using `::before` for the background and `::after` for the content.

```css
.fusion-layout-column {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fusion-column-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.fusion-column-wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 4em;
  background: #ddd;
}

.fusion-column-wrapper::after {
  content: 'G';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2em;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fusion-column-wrapper p {
  margin-left: 5em;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="fusion-layout-column">
  <div class="fusion-column-wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```